# Katta usage examples

Tags: java, lucene, katta

Does anybody use Katta with Java? Are any samples avalible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the tests [here](http://katta.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=katta/katta;a=tree;f=src/test/java/net/sf/katta;h=220660a5a2574c2531a657a90174380eb6db2c26;hb=refs/heads/master) and [here](http://katta.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=katta/katta;a=tree;f=src/test/integration/net/sf/katta/integrationTest;h=2d8cfc293748866f8bd88a5673285bf8f6338fb7;hb=refs/heads/master) for reference.

Comment: hm... I know about some tests and other useful code. But may be there are some articles/tutorials available?

Answer (score 0):

We are using. 
You can find samples in unit tests.